# Android Wear: Control smartwatch app through smartphone app

Tags: android, wear-os

Does anyone know if it's possible to control a smartwatch app (Android Wear) through a smartphone app. An example would be to switch to another page in the smartwatch app by clicking a button in the smartphone app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, there are API's to communicate wearable. For example you can send messages between phone and wearable using the [MessageApi](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/MessageApi.html). Check [this training page](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/messages.html) for how. Or you can use [BusWear library](https://github.com/tajchert/BusWear) for sending events between phone and wearable.